# Display equation 2-line equation in 3 columns

Tags: equations, multicolumn

I want to write in Latex the following equation:
[image: eq]

I tried to do this but it didn't quite work out

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:atmlineStrength}
\begin{split}
  S_i & = a_1\times10^{-7} \ p \ \theta^3 \exp{\left( a_2(1-\theta) \right)} & \text{for oxygen}\\
  & = b_1\times10^{-1} \ e \ \theta^{3.5} \exp{\left( b_2(1-\theta) \right)} & \text{for water vapour}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `split` to `aligned`, and you can add an extra `&` before the closing text, to get left-alignment on the right side.

I also implement Mico's suggestions: 1) `\exp` takes no argument, and 2) use `\bigl(...\bigr)` in lieu of `\left(...\right)`, for this use case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:atmlineStrength}
\begin{aligned}
  S_i & = a_1\times10^{-7} \ p \ \theta^3 \exp\bigl( a_2(1-\theta) \bigr) && \text{for oxygen}\\
  & = b_1\times10^{-1} \ e \ \theta^{3.5} \exp\bigl( b_2(1-\theta) \bigr) && \text{for water vapour}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Two comments: First, `\exp` doesn't take an argument. Second, if the OP wants the outer round parentheses to be enlarged, `\left` and `\right` isn't going to get the job done here. Hence, it would be better (and less clutter-y) to write `\exp\bigl( a_2(1-\theta) \bigr)` and `\exp\bigl( b_2(1-\theta) \bigr)`, respectively.